# Get id from slug when this page is the first being loaded

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I'd like to solve the following problem:

I created this route for my `vue-router`:

```
 {
    path: ':slug',
    name: 'category.view',
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "category-view" */ '@/js/pages/Category/View'),
},
```

If I link this route like this, I can access the ID of the category:

```
<router-link
        :to="{ name: 'category.view', params: {slug: url.slug, id: url.id } }"
        v-slot="{ href, route, navigate }">
...
</router-link>
```

This works fine. I can use the id in my component like this:

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, _from, next) {
    axios
    .get (`/api/category/${to.params.id}`).then ((resp) => {
        next ((vm) => {
            vm.category = resp.data.data;
        });
    });
},
```

But if the page is accessed without clicking the `router-link`, the `id` is missing. At the moment I am solving it this way, but this code smells :-D If there's no ID param, I am getting all categories and search for the one with the `slug` matching the `slug` from the request.

```
beforeRouteEnter (to, _from, next) {

    if (to.params.id) {
        axios
        .get (`/api/category/${to.params.id}`).then ((resp) => {
            next ((vm) => {
                vm.category = resp.data.data;
            });
        });
    } else {
        axios
        .get ('/api/category/index?length=-1').then ((resp) => {
            next ((vm) => {
                let categories = resp.data.data;

                categories.forEach (function (category) {
                    let result = category.fields.find (x => x.type === 'slug'); //each category has a field with the type "slug"

                    if (result.value === to.params.slug) {
                        axios
                        .get (`/api/category/${category.id}`).then ((resp) => {
                            vm.category = resp.data.data;
                        });
                    }
                });
            });
        });
    }
},
```

My question is: Is there a more elegant way to solve this problem using Vue & vue-router?

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want to use slug instead of just id?

Comment: Also, are you able to modify the API or the data in any way?

Comment: No, it‘s an external read-only API

Comment: Which API is it? I'll think on this for a bit for a client-side solution.

Comment: It's a custom API from an external service provider, which is not documented online. I thought about fetching all `categories` by my own API controller, searching for the slug and caching the result. What do you think?

Comment: So I guess I have a few questions still. How is someone accessing that page without an ID, just by visiting the page via the url input in the browser? Also, why does your route not include the id?

```{
    path: ':slug/:id',
    name: 'category.view',
    component: () => import( /* webpackChunkName: "category-view" */ '@/js/pages/Category/View'),
}
```